# angular4 testing input values after change

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I would to change value of my input while testing so I did:

```
const de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[formControlName="username"]'));
de.nativeElement.value = "10";
```

Then I submit the form:

```
component.onSubmit();
```

And the value of the input still is unchanged.
I tried to add

```
fixture.detectChanges();
```

After submit the form, but it actually does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you getting the element by the CSS selector?  Angular has a way to create [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) which are MUCH easier than what you're trying to do.  Take this example:

```
export class ReactiveFormExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor () { } 

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({ 
      'username': FormControl(null, [/** Any form validators here **/]) 
    });
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    // get the value of the username
    const username = this.form.get('username').value;
  }
}
```

If you really wanted to watch the value and detect the changes without pressing a button with an attached click event you would do this after initializing the form.

```
this.form.get('username').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  // new username value is `val`
});
```

Comment: But I'm writing about spec

Comment: @Stwosch you didn't specify that anywhere in the question or title, you would have gotten more responses if you made that clear

Comment: I wrote "testing" in title, in the description "I would to change value of my input while testing" and in my code, there are fixtures, that occurs in testing. Apart from it, in tags I included 'unit-testing', 'testing' and 'jasmine'

Comment: But thank you for your answer because I recognized that I can use setValue method instead of get and all went successful

Comment: @Stwosch you're absolutely right you did, my mistake